# What are the differences between Array map and rxjs map

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

I was wondering what the map on both rxjs and array works the same way. What are the differences between the uses of both the array map method and rxjs map operator?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `.map` in RxJS but that, itself, is a very general concept. It does not originate with JS arrays or JS at all - a mapping function always takes input of type A and produces output of type A or B (int -> int for `x => x*1` or int -> string for `x => "My number is: " + x`). In other contexts, you could have a container for one object and you use `container.map()` to interact with and change the underlying value (e.g., Java Optional) or you can use `.map` on an array to change all values. It's the same idea, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Array.map` transforms *each element* of a single array.

```js
console.log( [ 1, 2, 3 ].map(x => x * x) )
// log: [ 1, 4, 9 ]
```

---

In general, RXJS Observables are more like a stream of data, but each data is its own entity.

You may choose to store arrays in your Observable, but still, each array is treated like a single entity. Every time you call `Subject#next`, you're providing an entirely new array. In this scenario, there is no equivalent to `Array#push` with RXJS, because RXJS doesn't *care* that the content of the Observable happens to be an array.

```js
// Observable that holds an array as its type
const subject: Subject<number[]> = new Subject<number[]>();
subject.pipe(
  // the value here is a full array
  map(arr => arr.map(x => x * x))
).subscribe(arr => console.log(arr));

subject.next([ 1, 2, 3 ]);
// log: [ 1, 4, 9 ]

subject.next([ 7, 8, 9 ]);
// log: [ 49, 64, 81 ]
```

---

* Bonus : You can *kinda* make something act more like an array if you set up a `ReplaySubject`. This implementation of `Subject` literally replays all the data that was given to it (or a subset based on how you instantiate it). As you'll see though, the limitation to this would be that you can only push onto the end, and you have to create a new subscription to see the entire "array", but it's an interesting thought experiment nonetheless.

```js
const subject: ReplaySubject<number> = new ReplaySubject<number>();
subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
subject.next(3);

const transformed: Observable<number> = subject.pipe(
  map(x => x * x)
);

transformed.pipe(first()).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// log: 1
// log: 4
// log: 9

subject.next(9);
transformed.pipe(first()).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// log: 1
// log: 4
// log: 9
// log: 81
```

Answer (score 4):

Their functioning is quite the same, they give a new Array / Observable (respectively) with each element transformed according to (usually) a transformation function (the technical computer science name would be a *projection*), taking as parameter the modified object and its index.

[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is part of the prototype of Array natively. You can use it on any array in any JavaScript environment. (provided you didn't mess up the Array.prototype, of course)

[`Observable.map`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) must be imported. (For RxJS 6 : `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`, for older versions : `import { map } from 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`

---

### There is a small but significant difference

`Array.map` transformation function has access to the **whole array being transformed** (the third parameter in the projection function).

Exemple :

```js
     let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
     let arrResult = arr.map(
       (elem, index, wholeArray) => 'element ' + elem + ' was in position ' + index + ' in array ' + wholeArray);
     console.log(arrResult);
```

This is "of course" not possible (generally speaking) in the context of Observable since the "whole list" of emitted value is probably not known at the time each element is emitted.

---

On the opposite, there is another small  difference : `Observable.map` operator take an (optional) `thisArg` parameter, so the transformation function has access to some specified context.

I think this other difference is quite insignificant : `Array.map` doesn't need this, because it is a function and you can also specify your own "`this`" with the various ways of calling functions in JavaScript. (I don't find a nice link for this part, anyone who want to add a reference for this in this answer is welcome).

Also, I would find interesting to be challenged on that last point anyway.

Answer (score 2):

RxJS is for working with `Observables` and native `map` is for `Arrays`.
Thats the only diffrence I can think of.

Comment: so you think we use rxjs map operator the same way we use array map method to manipulate the data, or there are any differences?

Comment: Pac0 explained it better.