# Parse model filled with strings to another model filled with dates

Tags: angular, date, datetime, model, angular7

I get a list of objects with dates as strings from my backend.
I want to parse those strings to dates.

Data from backend looks like that:

```
      [{
        Date: '9/19/2018 12:00:00 AM',
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        Date: '9/19/2018 12:00:00 AM',
        id: 2,
      },
      ];
```

And I want to parse this response to model like that:

```
export class Order {
  Date: Date;
  id: number;
}
```

I think it should be something like that:

```
getOrders(user = this.user.id): Observable<Order[]> {
 return this.http.post<Order[]>(this.api_url + 'Orders/GetOrders', user)
   .pipe(
     map(
       orders => {
         this.order = orders
           .pipe(map(
            x => x.date = new Date(x.date);
            ));
         return orders;
       }
     )
   );}
```

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong please?
Or different way without dates parsing.

My problem is locally I have different dates format than on the server, and I want to unify that somehow to work in all countries well. When I use date pipes it throws invalid date in the table (date format on my PC locally is dd/MM/yyyy and at the server I have the same so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: But server still displays good dates only if I use MM/dd/yyyy format. Even if I changed date format in its system.

Answer (score 0):

The property you want to map is x.Date and not x.date.
It should start with a capital letter.

Comment: I changed models and names a little bit to make it more clear for you guys, so little issues like this don't matter.

Comment: all right...the RxJS map operator works different as the Array.prototype.map() method.

You can checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52754281/8712609